# Get users and groups list from Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

Hi I want to get the users and groups list from `Hadoop` in my java program. Is there any way of getting it from it's `API`? I googled a lot and haven't found anything yet.:(

Comment: Can you please elaborate on our question. You want to get the Linux users and groups in your hadoop program if at all you are running Hadoop on Linux???

Comment: I want to get the users and groups being used by hadoop. Like the files in hadoop have permissions on groups and users i want that list.

Comment: Presumably you mean the users/groups in, not "hadoop" but HDFS?  These are different things and saying "hadoop" when you mean "HDFS" can confuse people.  Which version of hadoop are you using?  In older version of HDFS users are not predefined, and can be created at will.  Code using the api to create a file can pass a random string in for username, and the created file in HDFS will be owned by that random string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the API but a robust way of getting the information would be to use a Offline Image Viewer that parses the fsimage of the name node and get the information in a XML format for say . You can then use a simple java API to parse the xml and get the list of users and groups.

Useful Links 
        a)  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html 
        b) https://github.com/twitter/hdfs-du

Answer (score 0):

You could get all users from hdfs://localhost:8020/user and get groups for those users using Groups (via ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping service)

Here is the code

```
    public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/path/to/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/path/to/hdfs-site.xml"));
        Groups g = new Groups(conf);

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        FileStatus[] files = fs.listStatus(new Path("/user"));
        for (FileStatus f : files) {
            Path p = f.getPath();


            try {
                List<String> gs = g.getGroups(p.getName());
                if (gs != null) {
                    System.out.println(p.getName() + " === " + gs.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No groups found for " + p.getName());
            }
        }

    }
}

java -cp myjar.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-hdfs.jar com.tools.Sample
```